# Add captions to very basic jquery carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I've seen this very simple jquery styled carousel on another thread and think it would be ideal for a project I'm doing but wondering how it could be adapted to include captions on the images?

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = "image_1.png";
path[1] = "image_2.png"; 
path[2] = "image_3.png"; 

function swapImage() { document.slide.src = path[i]; 
if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
else i = 0; setTimeout("swapImage()",2000); 
} window.onload=swapImage;

</script> 

<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
```

Any help or suggestions without having to overhaul the carousel would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You also need to make a list of captions and swap them in your `swapImage` function as you do with the `src` of the image.

Comment: Yeah!, I can see I need a caption list just not sure where to put them or declare the sub attribute

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var i = 0; var path = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = {img: "image_1.png", sub: "subtitle 1"};
path[1] = {img: "image_2.png", sub: "subtitle 2"}; 
path[2] = {img: "image_3.png", sub: "subtitle 3"}; 

function swapImage() {
document.slide.src = path[i].img;
document.subtitle.innerHTML = path[i].sub; 
if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
else i = 0; setTimeout("swapImage()",2000); 
} window.onload=swapImage;

</script> 

<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
<p name="subtitle"></p>
```

Comment: Hmm I think I can see how it could be done but for some reason this doesn't display the sub and doesn't change the image after timeout. Any idea how else could I declare the sub?

Comment: Well this seems the cleanest way to me, the problem must be at another part now. Could you place what you currently have in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, sample below, also notice, that demo uses `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```js
var i = 0;
var path = new Array();

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1";
path[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2";
path[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3";

function swapImage() {
  document.slide.src = path[i];
  // for the sake of example, we show urls of pictures
  document.querySelector('#slide_caption').textContent = path[i];
  if (i < path.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
}
setInterval(swapImage, 2000);
window.onload = swapImage;
```

```html
<h3 id="slide_caption"></h3>
<img height="200" name="slide" width="400" />
```

Comment: how would I make the subtitle display something other than the urls? add the subtitles into each path then suffix the src with .sub?